# C++ OpenAL will not play WAV file

Tags: c++, audio, openal

So I have written a method which is meant to accept a file path to a .wav file, go through the creation of buffers and sources, and play the sound. Apparently, no sound will actually play when I run the program. None of my error checks trigger, so there's nothing wrong with the file. I have scoured Google for the past few hours and have come up empty handed, so I wanted to ask here. Here is the code:

```
FILE* fp = NULL;

fp = fopen("audioFile.wav", "rb");

char type[4];
DWORD size, chunkSize;
short formatType, channels;
DWORD sampleRate, avgBytesPerSec;
short bytesPerSample, bitsPerSample;
DWORD dataSize;

fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if (type[0] != 'R' || type[1] != 'I' || type[2] != 'F' || type[3] != 'F')
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: No RIFF");

fread(&size, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if (type[0] != 'W' || type[1] != 'A' || type[2] != 'V' || type[3] != 'E')
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: Not a WAVE file");

fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if (type[0] != 'f' || type[1] != 'm' || type[2] != 't' || type[3] != ' ')
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: Not a fmt");

fread(&chunkSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
fread(&formatType, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
fread(&channels, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
fread(&sampleRate, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
fread(&avgBytesPerSec, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);
fread(&bytesPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);
fread(&bitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fp);

fread(type, sizeof(char), 4, fp);
if (type[0] != 'd' || type[1] != 'a' || type[2] != 't' || type[3] != 'a')
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: Missing DATA");

fread(&dataSize, sizeof(DWORD), 1, fp);

ALCdevice* device;
ALCcontext* context;

device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
if (!device)
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: No sound device detected");

context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
if (!context)
    fatalError("OpenAL Error: No sound context");

unsigned char* buf = new unsigned char[dataSize];
fread(buf, sizeof(BYTE), dataSize, fp);

ALuint source;
ALuint buffer;
ALuint frequency = sampleRate;
ALenum format = 0;

alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
alGenSources(1, &source);

if (bitsPerSample == 8)
{
    if (channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO8;
    else if (channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO8;
}
else if (bitsPerSample == 16)
{
    if (channels == 1)
        format = AL_FORMAT_MONO16;
    else if (channels == 2)
        format = AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
}

alBufferData(buffer, format, buf, dataSize, frequency);

ALfloat SourcePos[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
ALfloat SourceVel[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

// Listener
alListenerfv(AL_POSITION, ListenerPos);
alListenerfv(AL_VELOCITY, ListenerVel);
alListenerfv(AL_ORIENTATION, ListenerOri);

// Source
alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);
alSourcefv(source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);
alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);

alSourcePlay(source);

fclose(fp);
delete[] buf;

alDeleteSources(1, &source);
alDeleteBuffers(1, &buffer);
alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
alcDestroyContext(context);
alcCloseDevice(device);
```

Comment: Also, I understand that the way I'm checking for RIFF, WAVE and the other aspects are newbie, but I'm just learning OpenAL and plan to improve those sort of checks. I just want it to function before I worry about that :D.

Comment: You are closing the main program too fast. alSourcePlay starts playing your sound in the background, that means your have to wait for the sound to be played and THEN close your program. Just try to make a delay after alSourcePlay, that will help I guess :)

Comment: Alright, when I get the chance I'll try that out. Thanks for the response! :3

Comment: And did it work ? Wanna know :)

Comment: @HannesHauptmann sorry for responding so far into the future, but I restarted the project, so I haven't gotten to audio yet. I will make sure to let you know if your solution works when I get the chance to implement it again.